# create slow scroll in jquery or js when it go down or up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to create scroll but slower when moving down or up.
I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html").niceScroll
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look for `https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll`

this is a plugin for smooth scroll by click anchor scroll to content.

Comment: i don't want scroll go to element in site i want it be slow

Comment: for https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll have a look to CONFIGURATION PARAMETERS scrollspeed: so it will be eg. $(document).ready(function(){
    $("html").niceScroll({  scrollspeed: 60});
});